# Azure build task - build only one project from all solution

Tags: azure, azure-devops

i have an issue with azure task in ci/cd,
each release have an tests task that run before code deployed, and each time all solution build and it's take time.
i want that only specific project that related to the release will build and not all the solution.
how can i fix it?

Comment: Hi, how about the issue? Does the answer below resolve your question?

Answer (score 1):

According to your SO tags, it seems that you're using C#.

- To build one specific project that targets `.net framework` in build task:

  You should use [MSBuild task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/msbuild?view=azure-devops) instead of [Visual Studio Build task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/visual-studio-build?view=azure-devops).

  [image]
- To build one specific project that targets `.net core/standard` in build task:

  You should use [Dotnet build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops) with this kind of input:

  [image]
- Also if you're using Dotnet test in release task, it will automatically build the projects to test unless you add the `--no-build` switch. So you also need to make sure you're specifying specific project to test instead of using `**/*.csproj`.

  [image]

Answer (score 0):

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - master
    
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'
  demands:
    - msbuild
    - visualstudio

variables: 
  BuildConfiguration: "Release"
  platform: any cpu
  BuildPlatform: any cpu

name: 1.$(build.buildid)

stages:
- stage: Build
  jobs:
  - job: Build  
    steps:
    - task: NuGetToolInstaller@0
      displayName: 'Use NuGet 4.4.1'
      inputs:
        versionSpec: 4.4.1
    - task: NuGetCommand@2
      displayName: 'NuGet restore'
      inputs:
        restoreSolution: 'path to sln file/xxxxxxx.sln'
        vstsFeed: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'        
    - task: VSBuild@1
      displayName: 'Build solution'
      inputs:
        solution: 'path to sln file/xxxxxxx.sln'
        platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
        configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
        clean: true
```

Also, check-in Pipeline at the initial step if the respective sln file is selected
[image]